# Como inserir uma diretiva do Angular no HTML usando um script externo?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Preciso inserir uma diretiva dentro do código de um calendário que já está implementado em um site que estou criando, mas encontrei um problema: no HTML, a diretiva é impressa normalmente, mas o Angular não a processa e substitui seu conteúdo. No caso, eu modifiquei o script do calendário (o *fullCalendar.js*) para imprimir o elemento de uma diretiva minha do Angular, mas ela não compila.

Para exemplificar, fiz o seguinte exemplo: criei uma diretiva simples, que imprime "Olá mundo" onde ela for colocada. Coloquei uma tag `<ola-mundo>` no começo da página, que funciona como deve funcionar. Depois da página carregada, eu crio um novo elemento `<ola-mundo></ola-mundo>` usando Javascript simples, e coloco dentro do código da página. Esse segundo  não é compilado pelo Angular.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('olaMundo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p>Olá mundo</p>'
  };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var elemento = document.createElement('ola-mundo');
  var ola_mundo = document.getElementById('ola-mundo');
  ola_mundo.appendChild(elemento);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>
    <b>Aqui a diretiva deve imprimir normalmente:</b>
  </p>
  <ola-mundo></ola-mundo>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <p>
    <b>Aqui a diretiva é injetada por um script, e não funciona:</b>
  </p>
  <div id="ola-mundo"></div>
</body>
```

Consigo imaginar que a razão disso é por segurança, para outros scripts externos não executarem código do Angular. Sendo assim, de que outra forma posso injetar essa diretiva, já que o código do calendário é inserido por um script externo, que não faz parte do meu código?

Comment: Veja a restrição que você estás usando, 'E', 'A' ou 'C' ou 'EAC'?

Comment: [Recomendo fazer o curso](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/), eu fiz, vale a pena.

Comment: @IvanFerrer só usei o `E` nesse exemplo, mas não precisa mais que isso. Esse foi o curso que assisti quando comecei a usar Angular há uns meses, mas ele não se aprofunda nem um pouco. Foi ótimo pra começar, mas pra aprofundar o melhor lugar mesmo é a referência da framework.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque você está criando objetos do DOM sem dar ao Angular a oportunidade de compilá-los.

O código abaixo implementa criação dinâmica de diretivas e compilação via serviço `$compile`:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$compile) {

  $scope.adicionarDiretiva = function(){
    angular.element(
      document.getElementById('controlplaceholder'))
    .append($compile("<ola-mundo></ola-mundo>")($scope));
  };});

app.directive('olaMundo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p>Olá mundo</p>'
  };});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>
    <b>Aqui a diretiva deve imprimir normalmente:</b>
  </p>
  <ola-mundo></ola-mundo>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button ng-click='adicionarDiretiva()'>Criar dinamicamente</button>
  
  <br />
  <p>
    <b>Aqui a diretiva é injetada dinamicamente:</b>
  </p>
  <div id="controlplaceholder"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: O código que insere o `<ola-mundo>` não fica dentro do código do Angular, esse é o problema. É o script do calendário, que é só escrito usando jQuery (e não angular) que insere essa tag no DOM. Mas isso já explica metade da questão, que é sobre como compilar o código depois do próprio Angular o fazer. Outra pergunta: porquê colocar ($scope) depois do $compile, e sem usar um `.` entre eles?